# required field is false in bootstrap validation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am using a bootstrap validator for input/select fields. What I can't seem to do is turn off the validator for certain inputs. I've tried:

```
<form id="accordion">
    <input name="name" id="name" novalidate />
</form>

$('#accordion').validate({
     rules: {
         name: {
             required: false  
         } 
     },
     fields: {
         name: {
            required: false,
            validators: {
               required: false
            }
         }
     }
})
```

None of these worked. I also tried adding "novalidate" and "formnovalidate" to the individual input's but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check this post: [Form Validation With Bootstrap (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296267/form-validation-with-bootstrap-jquery)

I don't think you need to indicate when an input is not required, it's the opposite.