# form validation in bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have  a form in bootstrap 3. I am able to do basic validation with the has-error class. How do l check for specific user inputs like?

1. The user can only enter characters as first name and last name
2. The user can only enter numbers /digits as telephone number
3. The user can only enter valid email characters.

And also how can l output a more user friendly validation error messages. 
I'm new to bootstrap and any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <form method="post" id="contactform" action="" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon 
        glyphicon-user"></span></span>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon 
        glyphicon-user"></span></span>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon 
          glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" type="text" id="email" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon 
          glyphicon-earphone"></span></span>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" type="text" id="phone" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="contactbtn" class="btn btn- 
    primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateText(id) {

      if ($("#" + id).val() == null || $("#" + id).val() == "") {
        var div = $("#" + id).closest("div");
        div.addClass("has-error");
        return false;

      } else {

        var div = $("#" + id).closest("div");
        div.removeClass("has-error");
        return true;
      }
    }

    $(document).ready(
      function() {
        $("#contactbtn").click(function() {

          if (!validateText("firstname")) {
            return false;
          }

          if (!validateText("lastname")) {
            return false;
          }

          if (!validateText("email")) {
            return false;
          }
          if (!validateText("phone")) {
            return false;
          }
          $("form#contactform").submit();
        });
      }
    );
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML input fields have an attribute called `pattern` which you can use for ensuring a specific input with a regex.

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="First Name"
name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" pattern="^\w*$" />
...
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" 
type="text" id="lastname" pattern="^\w*$" />
...
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" 
type="text" id="email" pattern="^[^@\\s]+@[^@\\s]+\\.[^@\\s]+$" />
...
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" 
type="text" id="phone" pattern="^\d*$" />
```

That's just a simple sample e-mail regex. There are lot of other regex for e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery boostrap validation.It's much easy.you can follow following 
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296267/form-validation-with-bootstrap-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to tweak things if you want to use something else. But this is preferably used in bootstrap way.

```js
var showErrorSuccess = function(element, status) {
  if (status === false) {
    element.parent().next().removeClass('hidden').parent().addClass('has-error');
    return false;
  }
  element.parent().next().addClass('hidden').parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
};

var validate = function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  //validate name
  var name = $('#firstname').val();
  if (name.length < 3) {
    return showErrorSuccess($('#firstname'), false);
  }
  showErrorSuccess($('#firstname'));

  var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
  if (lastname.length < 3) {
    return showErrorSuccess($('#lastname'), false);
  }
  showErrorSuccess($('#lastname'));

  //validate email
  var email = $('#email').val(),
    emailReg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/
  if (!emailReg.test(email) || email == '') {
    return showErrorSuccess($('#email'), false);
  }
  showErrorSuccess($('#email'));

  //validate phone
  var phone = $('#phone').val(),
    intRegex = /[0-9 -()+]+$/;
  if ((phone.length < 6) || (!intRegex.test(phone))) {
    return showErrorSuccess($('#phone'), false);
  }
  showErrorSuccess($('#phone'));
};
```

```css
body>form {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form class="form-vertical" method="post" id="contactform" onSubmit="javascript:validate()" action="" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon 
    glyphicon-user"></span></span>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" />
      </div>
      <p class="help-block hidden">Please enter a name 3 characters or more.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon 
    glyphicon-user"></span></span>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" />
      </div>
      <p class="help-block hidden">Please enter a name 3 characters or more.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon 
      glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
        <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" id="email" />
      </div>
      <p class="help-block hidden">Please enter a valid email address.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon 
      glyphicon-earphone"></span></span>
        <input class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" type="phone" id="phone" />
      </div>
      <p class="help-block hidden">Please enter a valid phone number.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried the code above and l'm not getting any validation. I'm guessing it has to do with the js code. I tried placing the js code in the head section and also tried it right before the closing body tag still no luck. What is the right way to go?

Comment: Removed the functions out of $(document).ready(). Now its working. Other way is instead of calling method in html `onSubmit=xyz()` you can bind the method to element with `.on()` of jquery.

Comment: thanks a lot. The code is now working, l will tweaking it a bit to add more but you definitely showed me the way.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of using the correct input `type` as well as declaring a `pattern` attribute can likely preclude the need for any special JavaScript.

1) The user can only enter characters as first name and last name

For this you need to rely on `<input type="text">` which by default allows basically anything.  So we'll need to apply a `pattern` that restricts this field to only letters:

`<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]+">`

2) The user can only enter numbers /digits as telephone number

Depending on your needs this could be as simple as using the correct input `type`:

`<input type="tel">`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel

Because different countries have different patterns you may want to improve this with the addition of a `pattern` attribute.

`<input type="tel" pattern="^[0-9\-\+\s\(\)]*$">`

This will allow your number inputs to be a bit more flexible, accept dashes and parenthesis, allow the user to specify a +DIGIT country code, etc.

3) The user can only enter valid email characters.

Again using the correct input `type` will greatly simplify your validation efforts:

`<input type="email">`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email

This is another one that can be a little 'fuzzy' when you're comparing certain input types as it really just looks for `handle@domain.extension`.  You can read more about its specific validation patterns using the above link to Mozilla's developer toolkit.

Answer (score -1):

Here is easy and best concept to use form validation by using custom jquery/javascript code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
  <body>

 <form method="post" id="contactform" action="" role="form">
 <div class="form-group">

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon 
    glyphicon-user"></span></span>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" 
    name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon 
    glyphicon-user"></span></span>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" 
   type="text" id="lastname" />
    </div>
   </div>

    <div class="form-group">

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon 
      glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
        <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email"    type="email" id="email" />
    </div>
   </div>

<div class="form-group">

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon 
      glyphicon-earphone"></span></span>
        <input class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" 
     type="phone" id="phone" />
    </div>
</div>

    <button type="button" id="contactbtn" onclick="validateText();" class="btn btn- 
primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">

  function validateText(id){
   //validate name
var name = $('input[id="firstname"]').val();
if (name.length < 3)
{
    alert('Please enter a name 3 characters or more.');
    return false;
}
var lastname = $('input[id="lastname"]').val();
if (name.length < 3)
{
    alert('Please enter a name 3 characters or more.');
    return false;
}

//validate email
var email = $('input[id="email"]').val(),
    emailReg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/
if(!emailReg.test(email) || email == '')
{
     alert('Please enter a valid email address.');
     return false;
}

//validate phone
var phone = $('input[id="phone"]').val(),
    intRegex = /[0-9 -()+]+$/;
if((phone.length < 6) || (!intRegex.test(phone)))
{
     alert('Please enter a valid phone number.');
     return false;
}
 }

 
 </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```